# .NET Core - ILogger DI and Base Classes/Object Classes

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I must be missing something on DI in .NET Core and I'd need your help.
I've been using DI successfully for my Service Classes, my Azure Client classes etc etc, but I can't understand how to get that working with my base classes (classes that just represent a basic object).

Let's say I have a vary simple class like

```
        public class Person{

          private readonly Ilogger<Person> logger;

          public string name {get; set;}
          public string lastname {get; set;}
          public void LogYourName(){
             logger.logInformation(this.name);
          }
        }
```

Also, let's say I have a HTTP rest API or another service that return as result an instance of `Person`.

How can I initiate `ILogger` in `Person` class without using DI?

Comment: Why would you want a logger on your model, rather then the controller or service.  On the controller and service you could simply do the `logger.ForContext<Class>` to indicate the location in which the logger is executing.

Comment: For using dependencies into entities, [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/) is a better approach. This means: inject `ILogger` into a service class and pass it on from that service to the `Person.LogYourName` method as a method argument. This way `Person` can use that dependency without having to store that dependency. Storing runtime data and design time dependencies in the same class is [a bad idea](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Dependency Injection framework requires you to implement via the Constructor.  You would need to do:

```
public class Person
{
     private readonly ILogger logger;
     public Person(ILogger logger) => this.logger = logger;

     // Additional Code Here
}
```

When the object is constructed the framework will inject the logger instance for you. However, based on your above question-  to avoid the the Dependency Injection would need to do:

```
var logger = services.GetService<ILogger>();
var person = new Person(logger);
```

The `services` would derive from `IServiceProvider`.  I would need to see how you instantiate the `IServiceCollection` and populate your `IServiceProvider`.  That would allow you to manually put the interface into the class while still using the Microsoft Dependency Injection framework.

Comment: Maybe my question was not 100% clear.

Comment: @EmilioPetrangeli: In that case it would be good to update your question to make it more clear.